# Vue.js component communication with children components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to make a slider in Vue
I have 2 components "Slider" and "SliderItem"
A "Slider" can have multiple "SliderItem"s
how can I communicate between these two components internally

example usage

```
<Slider>
    <SliderItem>
        <h1>Slide 1</h1>
    </SliderItem>
    <SliderItem>
        <h1>Slide 2</h1>
    </SliderItem>
</Slider>
```

Slider Component

```
<template>

    <div>
        <slot :i="index"></slot>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return { index : 0 };
    }
};
</script>
```

How can I pass the current index to the children (SliderItem)s

so I can show/hide them according to the index passed from the parent (Slider)

and in the same way how can I achieve children to parent communication

for example in React it can be done like this

```
const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children,
 (child) => React.cloneElement(child, {
   index: this.state.index
 })
);
```

I want to do the same thing in Vue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kumar_14's answer is mostly correct
but he edited the HTML which I didn't want to do in order to make the usage of the plugin as simple and small as possible

But I found an easier way to do it by using this.$parent from the child to access the parent's data

HTML

```
<div id="root">
  <slider>
    <slider-item :key="1">
      <h1>Slide 1</h1>
    </slider-item>
    <slider-item :key="2">
      <h1>Slide 2</h1>
    </slider-item>
    <slider-item :key="3">
      <h1>Slide 3</h1>
    </slider-item>
    <slider-item :key="4">
      <h1>Slide 4</h1>
    </slider-item>
  </slider>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var Slider = Vue.component("slider", {
  template: "<div><button @click=\"prev\">Prev</button><slot></slot><button @click=\"next\">Next</button></div>",
  data() {
    return { index: 1 };
  },
  methods: {
    next() {
      this.index = this.index === this.childrenLength ? 1 : this.index + 1;
    },
    prev() {
      this.index = this.index === 1 ? this.childrenLength : this.index - 1;
    }
  },
  computed: {
    childrenLength() {
      return this.$children.length;
    }
  }
});

var SliderItem = Vue.component("slider-item", {
  template: "<div v-if=\"$vnode.data.key === $parent.index\"><slot></slot></div>"
});

new Vue({
  el : "#root",
  components: {
    "slider": Slider,
    "slider-item": SliderItem
  }
});
```

[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/dixuliw/2/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 2):

Use [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props) to pass data down to the children, and [events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events) to pass data from the children back to the parent. Child to child communication is done via the parent.

Please study the docs carefully as you will find most of the things you need there. Good luck!

Comment: I already know how basic communication works events up and props down including event busses. My question is how do you achieve Component to child Components communication internally. example code above.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by internally, can you clarify more?

Comment: so for example in the Slider component how can I pass the (index) to its children which are (SliderItem)s. and what I mean by internally is that I don't want to change the HTML code I want the communication to be between(Slider) and (SliderItem) only

Comment: Other than using props/events, event bus or vuex, I don't really know. I still do not understand how you get a scenario where passing props/events is not a solution since its a staple of inter component communication.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you, first wrap your inner components in a template with a scope defined, as and provide the inner components the index as prop,

```
<Slider>
   <template scope="sliderItemScope">
     <SliderItem :parent-index="sliderItemScope.i">
        <h1>Slide 1</h1>
     </SliderItem>
     <SliderItem :parent-index="sliderItemScope.i">
        <h1>Slide 2</h1>
     </SliderItem>
   </template>
</Slider>
```

Then in slider component:

```
<template>

    <div>
        <slot :i="index"></slot>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return { index : 0 };
    }
};
</script>
```

Then in sliderItem component you can access index as i prop:

```
props:['parentIndex']
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer already said, you should use props. I think you're focusing too much on how to implement your solution in a react way with vue. You can do it using React or Vue, no need to mix them. The HTML template code is a markup that gets parsed by Vue, it will NOT be part of the rendered DOM but instead handled.

To re-iterate, the HTML gets converted to JavaScript, so your props will not be seen in the DOM.